# How to to JOIN 2 tables with foreign key pointing to other table primary key to return all the row that have such primary key in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

Please help I need to get rows in the 2 tables with the foreign key poiting to table_a as seen on picture. I have tried Joining this way,

```
SELECT * FROM table_a 
INNER JOIN table_b
ON table_a.id = table_b.my_col
INNER JOIN table_c
ON table_a.id = table_c.my_col
```

but it return empty results. Please help me to fix such SQL JOIN statement

PLEASE LOOK AT THE PHOTO I MADE WHICH SHOW THESE TABLES AND MORE ELABORATION

[image]

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained. Insert images/links using edit functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could be that you have not valid match in table_b and table_c  (your id for table_a don't match values  in table_b and table_c)

try use left join

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_a 
LEFT  JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.my_col
LEFT  JOIN table_c ON table_a.id = table_c.my_col
```

Comment: "not valid match in table_b and table_c" - I would say "no valid match in table_b **or** table_c".

Comment: Thanks you at guys, #scaisEdge answer shows better results with offcourse some nulls, but the required rows are present. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It worked. Its the results I needed. Thank you yet more!